# Helper file parentheses not carrying over

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-console

I cannot for the life of me get this to work right. What is happening is I'm writing a .vbs file to the %temp% folder as a helper file. Then I'm calling it. It's all working except one single ")" character is not carrying over.

```
set "path=\\server1\folder\folder\folder\dest-folder"
set source=^"%path%\nwm*.zip^"
set destination=%path%

setlocal
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('dir/b "%destination%\nwm*.zip"') do (
    set source=%%a
    :unzip
    >> %temp%\unzip.vbs echo ^'test
    >> %temp%\unzip.vbs echo call WindowsUunzip(%source%,"%destination%")
    >> %temp%\unzip.vbs echo Function WindowsUunzip(sUunzipFileName, sUunzipDestination)

    C:\windows\system32\cscript //nologo %temp%\unzip.vbs
    pause
    if exist "%temp%\unzip.vbs" del /f /q "%temp%\unzip.vbs"
    endlocal
)
```

This is the result I'm getting:

```
'test
call WindowsUunzip("\\server1\folder\folder\folder\dest-folder\nwm*.zip","\\server1\folder\folder\folder\dest-folder"
Function WindowsUunzip(sUunzipFileName, sUunzipDestination)
```

This is the result I'd like to see (A ")" symbol on the first line at the end.)

```
'test
call WindowsUunzip("\\server1\folder\folder\folder\dest-folder\nwm*.zip","\\server1\folder\folder\folder\dest-folder")
Function WindowsUunzip(sUunzipFileName, sUunzipDestination)
```

What I've tried so far:

- Using @echo, echo(, echo:
- escaping all the parentheses
- Adding extra lines of code just for the sake of watching the behavior.
- removing the for loop it works fine, but I need to iterate through the files and call this VBS function on each file.

Comment: Inside a (code block) other closing parentheses have to be escaped with a caret `^)` to not end the code block prematurely.

Comment: When I escape them the bat just errors out then exits

Comment: "the bat just errors out" is not helpful.  Run it from the command line.  Report the error you see.  If you are double clicking the bat, don't until it works.

Comment: C:\Users\THOMAS~1.MAU\AppData\Local\Temp\2\unzip.vbs(4, 1) Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected 'End'

Comment: So it writes the file then tries to open it and since we know we are missing a parentheses we get the expected result...

Comment: The `for` loop seems over-complicated. Why not use `for %%a in ("%destination%\nwm*.zip") do`?

Comment: Tried it, same result. Missing parentheses in the same exact place

Comment: Man, I thought this would have been an easy fix.

Comment: Line **1**, overwrite of reserved `%path%` variable. Line **2**, carets not needed. Line **6**, `for` loop command use `%source%` instead of `%destination%`. Line **7**, overwrite `%source%`. Line **8**, label in code block. Line **9**, caret not needed. Line **10**, need caret `^)` and need delayed expansion. Line **11**, need caret `^)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set "Xpath=\\server1\folder\folder\folder\dest-folder"
set source=^"%Xpath%\nwm*.zip^"
set destination=%Xpath%

setlocal
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('dir/b "%destination%\nwm*.zip"') do (
    >> %temp%\unzip.vbs echo ^'test
    >> %temp%\unzip.vbs echo call WindowsUunzip(%%a,"%destination%"^)
    >> %temp%\unzip.vbs echo Function WindowsUunzip(sUunzipFileName, sUunzipDestination^)

    C:\windows\system32\cscript //nologo %temp%\unzip.vbs
    pause
    if exist "%temp%\unzip.vbs" del /f /q "%temp%\unzip.vbs"
)
endlocal
```

**PATH** is the sequence of directories searched by windows to find an executable if it isn't found in the current directory. You change it at your peril.

Are you aware that the values `set` before the `setlocal` command are permanently `set` into this session's environment?

It's more normal to examine the `source` not the `destination` for files in your `for /f` directory-scan.

Using a label within a `for` loop is almost guaranteed to give trouble. I suspect you've censored out (quite acceptable in generating a minimal script) a significant `goto unzip` statement within the `for` loop (you can't `goto` a destination within a `for` loop.)

and your `endlocal` should be *outside* of the `for` loop, otherwise it gets exectuted for each loop value invoked.

Finally, are you aware that

```
> %temp%\unzip.vbs echo ^'test
```

(note a single `>`) will start a new file `%temp%\unzip.vbs`, replacing any existing version? That may save you the gated-delete (but you'd need to delete the file [if you so desire] after the `for` loop closes)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) option for what I think you're trying to do:

```bat
<!-- :
@Echo Off
Set "destination=\\server1\folder\folder\folder\dest-folder"
Set "file-mask=nwm*.zip"
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where "%destination%":"%file-mask%"'
)Do CScript //NoLogo "%~f0?.wsf" "%%A" "%destination%"
Exit /B
-->
<Job><Script Language="VBScript">
    Unzip WScript.Arguments(0), WScript.Arguments(1)
    Sub Unzip(sSource, sTargetDir)
        Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If Not oFSO.FolderExists(sTargetDir) Then oFSO.CreateFolder(sTargetDir)
        Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        Set oSource = oShell.NameSpace(sSource).Items()
        Set oTarget = oShell.NameSpace(sTargetDir)
        oTarget.CopyHere oSource, 256
    End Sub
    </Script></Job>
```

You can obviously adjust your `VBScript` code to suit your exact purpose, but this should offer you a methodology.